# Google Analytics Goals with Sub-domains

Tags: web-applications, reporting, google-analytics

We are releasing a paid web application. We have Google Analytics and want to set up conversion goals to see who signs up on the various accounts. I.e. what demographic is buying the highest plan, etc. The problem is that Google Analytics assumes that it is tracking a single domain, and our application operates on several sub-domains (signup.ourapp.com, accounts.ourapp.com, user-subdomain.ourapp.com).

So my question is: is there a way to use wild-card domains with Google Analytics, specifically when creating conversion goals? Our goals would look something like this:

1. http://www.ourapp.com/signup
2. http://accounts.ourapp.com/signup/[plan-name] (This will be different for each goal)
3. http://[user-account].ourapp.com/dashboard (Goal)

The Google Analytics Goal Settings page asks you to put in the paths of the goals, not the full URLs (i.e. /signup not www.ourapp.com/signup). Also, I am not sure if you can even put the Google Analytics JavaScript code on multiple domains and have it track it properly.

Does anyone have any input on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to Google's FAQ on multiple sub-domains:

<del>http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55524</del>

And here is the info on multiple domains:

<del>http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55503</del>

UPDATE: Looks like everything is here now:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: The second link mentions " your analytics tracking code must be placed on the page above the call to _link" - but analytics instructions says this code must be just before closing body tag. How can one account for that difference?

Comment: Would this let you see both the aggregate stats and the stats for just one subdomain?  Even if there are hundreds or thousands of subdomains?

I'm trying to figure out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151190/web-analytics-for-platform-with-custom-events

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else finding this thread, the final solution was to use "Equals to" and then type in the domain in full without the http://

So, www.domainname.com/xxx/ or domainname.com/xxx/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great [guide](http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/) to setting up multiple subdomains:.

I still struggle with your original question however, how to enter the URI when adding goals...