# Google Analytics goals and multiple subdomain sites

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup common analytics across several subdomains by following google's guide at http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034342 This works and is reporting nicely.

The next step is to setup goals to report important interactions.  The advice in google's guide is to use a regex to pull out destination  goals.   I'm testing and so far i can only get regexs to match the url after the domain part,   what i want to do is get a sequence of goals on different sites e.g. www.A.com/catalogue  to  www.B.com/register  to  www.B.com/buy   I've got the tracking code and filters setup  but i can't get destination goal regex's to match to the "www.A.com" part of the url just the "/catalogue" part.

Can destination goals distinguish between the full url of the page?  Are there any good guides on setting up the reporting for cross site tracking?

I've searched for how to setup goals with sub domain tracking but can't find anything, there are plenty of articles on have to setup the tracking side, but there is nothing on how to setup goal reporting. Someone asked here 5 years ([Google Analytics Goals with Sub-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505561/google-analytics-goals-with-sub-domains)) ago but didn't get an answer on how to enter a full URI into to goals.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is setup a [virtual pageview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews) for each step of your funnel. So, for instance, you want to track:

Step 1: www.A.com/catalogue
Step 2: www.B.com/register
Step 3: www.B.com/buy

Destination URL: www.B.com/thankyou

Now, add a virtual pageview to each section you'd like to track:

Example:

User is on www.A.com/catalogue, fire a virtual pageview something like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/funnel/catalogue']);
```

This way, the the funnel steps aren't dependent on the full URL string, just the virtual pageview.

The only caution about virtual pageviews is that they are firing off a pageview, so your pageview count will be skewed.